# Writing bitarray to file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compression

doing this in byte is easy with filestream, but I cant get it to work with a bitarray.

I want to develop file compression algorithms, just as a hobby.

The method in question checks if the combined occurence of three combination of bytes occur enough times for the filesize to benefit from adding two bits at the beginning of every byte, as to whether the next byte is one of the three pre-stored bytes, if both bits are zero it assumes no, and just continues reading the file. now writing another byte for each byte would make all of this redundant.

If someone could tell me how to do this, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Your question is not clear... you want to save a bitarray to a file?

Comment: As already said, the questions is not entirely clear, but perhaps use [`BitArray.CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) to populate a byte array and write those bytes to the file?

Comment: yes I want to write a bitarray to a file, now the biggest problem (from my understanding) if I write it to a byte array and the result is not divisible by 8, I will write extra bits to the file. couldnt that corrupt the file?

Comment: @Barny Not sure what you mean - I don't believe you can read/write less than a byte to a file, so you can't just write 2 bits + 1 byte to a file.  You would have to convert your compressed data into actual bytes by manipulating the bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I want to do it, it is not possible. Extra bits are inevitable as the smallest unit which by the hard drive can be written to is a byte. the extra bits have to be dealt with in the logic of decompression. a bulletproof solution is to add some extra bits at the beginning of the file (or wherever the metadata is stored for the filecompression) which represent the cutoff in the last byte. 3 bits is enough as you can represent the number 7 with it. (obviously there isn't a whole extra unnecessery byte, therefor if the compressed file is still divisible by eight these three bits should be 000 or numerically a zero, 8 does not need to be written) this way once the last byte is being read the program should ignore as many bits as the three bits equal to.